# Probability (Multivariate distributions )

Tags: probability

A two-dimensional continuous random variable $(X,Y)$ has a joint probability density function given by

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
6(1-x) & (x,y)\in R \\
0 & (x,y)\notin R \\
\end{cases}$$

where $R$ is the region bounded by the lines $y=0$, $x=1$ and $y=x$.

1. Draw the graph of $f(x,y)$.
2. Find the marginal probability density function of $X$.
3. Find the marginal probability density function of $Y$.

Comment: Are you sure about that region?  Those three lines don't bound any region.

Comment: Yes.....It is a question from my college ...

Comment: sorry ...I have a mistake...It must be x=1 in fifth line...        I edited it in my question

Comment: That's better; the base is a triangle.  So, can you graph the pyramid?

Comment: I don't know how to draw it......But I think it is the area bounded by lines x=1,y=0 and y=x..

Comment: The base is the triangle $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0)$.  The forth apex of the tetrahedron is $(0,0,6)$.  Plot these vertices, connect the points.

Comment: Ok....I got it.....so please can you answer for the other two questions also...

Comment: Here we have to intergrate f(x,y)from 0 to1 to find marginal probability density function of X. There I got an answer 6(1-x).When I intergrate f(x,y) from 0 to x to find marginal probability density function of Y I got an answer 3x(2-x)..Please can you tell me that whether I am correct or not..

Comment: Think carefully.  What is the support for $Y$ when given $X=x$?  (Draw the triangle, draw a vertical line through it.  $Y$ goes from...to...)  Likewise what is the support for $X$ when given $Y=y$?

Comment: Ok.....thank you very much .....

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn't a site that will solve your homework for you, and **some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown**. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

Think carefully.  What is the support for $Y$ when given $X=x$?  (Draw the triangle, draw a vertical line through it.  $Y$ goes from...to...)  Likewise what is the support for $X$ when given $Y=y$?

$$\newcommand{\hide}[1]{\bbox[border:dotted 1pt salmon]{\phantom {#1}}}{\displaystyle f_X(x) ~{=~ \mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}\int_\hide 0^\hide x 6(1-x)\,\mathrm d y  \\ =~ \hide{6x(1-x)}~\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}}\\ \displaystyle f_Y(y) ~{=~ \mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]}\int_\hide y^\hide 1 6(1-x)\,\mathrm d x \\ = \hide {3(1-y)^2}\;\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]}}}$$

Comment: Love the visual aid: +1